# Query string variable "do" with value "ninja" appearing in search results

Tags: google-search, wordpress

I did a generic Google search to see if my site shows up somewhere on the first page and it did, however I am seeing a strange query string in the place where you would normally see a plain url to the article (green url under the main link title on a SERP):

```
domain.net/?do=ninja
```

I tried searching for what it could mean but didn't find anything related to the topic.

Is my site infected with some malware? (I'm using WordPress if that changes anything).

Comment: I didn't find anything, but if you ever need to search Google only in the urls to find other infected domains, you can use `allinurl:some-part-of-url` to see if its something mass

Answer (score 1):

What is your default URL set to in Webmaster?

Webmaster also gives you the ability to [identify query strings](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters) and how they relate to your site. This also automatically identifies query strings it's found on your site - check the list to see if this one appears.

It's also worth checking your backlink profile, in case Google has discarded defaults in favour of a popular link it's found with identical content to your main page. What it will do in this circumstance is assume that your default is a duplicate of the popular link - replacing it. You can use the same URL parameters console to eliminate Google viewing this query string as a valid modifier.

Comment: I have both domain.net and www.domain.net, but the default is domain.net. Nothing appears in the query strings list though and now the url I asked about is gone from SERP too. No idea what it was :/

Comment: That might be one of those irritating little mysteries. Don't look a gift horse in the mouth and just be glad it's gone :D